# How does MFR's Laser Drill's "consume power - generate ore" process work itself out by power-unit-ratio?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

So MFR's [Laser Drill](http://ftbwiki.org/Laser_Drill) consumes vast amounts of energy through [Laser Drill Prechargers](http://ftbwiki.org/Laser_Drill_Precharger) and in return generates ores for you and your in-laws. Good stuff. My question is, assuming vast amounts of energy are not within your evil grasp, would it be faster to have

- 2 Laser Drills - each operating on one or more Laser Drill Prechargers (neither maxed out)

Or

- 1 Laser Drill - operating on one or more Laser Drill Prechargers (neither maxed out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Laser Drill page you linked:

> No matter the number of prechargers, it will take 600,000 MJ, 6,000,000 RF or 1,500,000 EU for each block generated.

So both options are equally as fast. However, if you'd be splitting your available power equally between two drills, you would have to wait longer between block generations. You would have to wait for 1,200,000 MJ to generate two blocks. With one drill, you would wait for 600,000 MJ for one block generated. It's the same rate overall and it's dependent on your energy production.